# Can anyone explain how this constraint functions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone explain how this constraint functions and how its affects insertion of records into this table? Running win sql 2k5. Having issue with trying to insert data.

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ws_shiptable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ws_shiptable_ps_processed]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [ps_processed]
```

Answer (score 1):

It adds a default value of 0 for column `ps_processed`. If you do an insert and you don't specify a value for ps_processed, it'll default to 0. What is the issue you are having? Do you get error messages you can post? A default value shouldn't give you trouble, but make sure ps_processed has the right data type. I suspect it'll be a bit field?

Answer (score 0):

If no value is provided for the column `ps_processed` then SQL Server will set the value to zero